# Start an Android Service without the .class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am looking for a way to start an Android-Service without the class.
I found many examples like:

```
startService(new Intent(this, TheService.class));
```

I don't want to put the service class in it and still have the service running till I stop it manually.

I don't need to have the Interface of the service, because it only should open some Sockets without any parameters.

The service running time should not depend on the running time of an App:
The first App which needs the Service should start it and than it should run until it is stopped manually.

So I can't use `BroadcastReceiver` because they live to short.
Binding to a Service will lead to unbind which stopps the service(which I don't want).

Is there any way to use start service without the .class of the service?
Alternative:
Is there a way to bind to service which does not link the lifetime to the started app?

Comment: Just because it might lead to a wrong design decision: _I can't use BroadcastReceiver because they live too short_ sounds very much like you don't yet know that while the lifecycle of BroadcastReveivers and Services, the reasoning is still wrong because one _can_ start a long-running Service via a BroadcastReveiver. Also, _binding_ to a Service has of course something to do with the lifecycle of an Application of Activity object, but the _binding_ time span does not necessarily have to match the Service's _running_ period. SO don't make a design decision based on misunderstandings.

Comment: If your `Service` wants to control its own lifetime you can still do this using bind/unbind. When a client binds, the `Service` can then start itself (simply by calling `startService()` in `onBind()`) so that when the client unbinds the `Service` isn't automatically stopped. The `Service` can then stop itself whenever it is ready to shutdown.

Answer (score 7):

You can start it by name.  Like this:

```
public static void startYourService(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent("com.whatever.servicename.YOUR_ACTION_NAME");
    i.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
    context.startService(i);
}
```

You'll need to add an intent filter to the apk with the service:

```
<service
    android:name="com.whatever.servicename"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.whatever.servicename.YOUR_ACTION_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "start it by name", you really mean "start it by Intent ACTION". Theoretically, your "com.whatever.servicename" could also be "fred-and-ethel-take-out-the-garbage", or "GobbledyGook123" although by convention the ACTION key should begin with a fully-qualified package name to avoid conflicts. When you start a service with an ACTION like this, Android searches all installed packages to find a service that has an Intent filter that matches this ACTION.